# Contact form issue Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

do we require an smtp extension for a live server?

https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension

I tried every possible solution, but nothing happened

Comment: How is your SMTP server setup? What have you tried? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: well am new to magento i dont know much about it .i have used extension for smtp configuration ,does it really required in live site

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "required in live site" but you need an smpt service running somewhere to be able to send an email. the issue might be that you misconfigured it on the extension level, or the service is not set up properly or not allowing access from your server to a bug in your code. unless you give us some more detail we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your exception.log to get to the bottom of this. Mostly it is about misconfiguration of sendmail or smtp-relay.

you may try to run a test script with the same data you entered in contact form and configured in magento

```
<?php 
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "from@YOURDOMAIN";
    $to = "to@YOURDOMAIN";
    $subject = "subject";
    $message = "message";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "email has been sent";
?>
```

also check this for testing
https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.mail.introduction.html